# Webpack Error trying to connect to mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, next.js13

Since today, when I try to connect to mongodb using mongoose within a Next.js application, I get the error below. Anyone have any idea what to do?

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).connect is not a function
> at mongoDBConnection

app/new/FileUpload.tsx:

```
import mongoDBConnection from "../lib/mongoDb";

useEffect(()=> mongoDBConnection()),[]}
```

app/lib/mongoDB.ts:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const mongoDBConnection = async () =>
await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL as string);

export default mongoDBConnection;
```

next.config.js:

```
 /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
 const nextConfig = {
 webpack: (config) => {
 config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };

 return config;
},
 reactStrictMode: true,
 experimental: {
 serverActions: true,
 appDir: true,
 serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"],
 },
 images: {
  domains: ["fakestoreapi.com", "firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
 },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done. The solutions was that i have to make the connection call on the server side. So in next it has to be inside app/api/ folder.